# OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener not working as intended

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, listener, android-sharedpreferences

I have an app that uses Android's SharedPreferences. I'm using an OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener to do some action when my ListPreference is changed. I initialize my OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in my MainActivity's `onStart()` method and register it. I unregister it in `onStop()`. For some reason it is not working at all. If I register it in the Activity's `onCreate()` and never unregister it seems works fine. Why is this? This is even happening when I first launch the Activity and try changing the preferences, hence `onStop()` is never getting called and the listener is never getting unregistered. The relevant code is below:

```
private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener prefListener;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scoring);

        // Initialize our game rules preference to its default value
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

        setupViews(GameEngine.BAGS_PER_ROUND);
        startNewGame();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        prefListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
                if (key.equals("game_mode_list")) {
                    startNewGame();
                    Log.d(TAG, "ListPreference clicked");
                }
            }
        };
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // Unregister changeListener to prevent leaks (although Android uses a weak reference)
        prefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefListener);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using .apply() or .commit() to update the shared pref?

Comment: I'm not updating the preferences, only reading from them.

Comment: onSharedPreferenceChanged will only be triggered when you change the shared prerence that you registered the listener. So, I expect that in some place you are getting an editor, than using a .commit() or a .apply() to update the shared pref file.

Comment: In my preferences.xml I have a ListPreference with 2 items, its ID is "game_mode_list", that is the key I am checking for. So when I select one item or the other in that ListPreference I want the `startNewGame()` method to fire. It is working when it is in `onCreate()`

Answer (score 0):

`getDefaultSharedPreferences()` will get the **default** preferences file for your app. If you're trying to listen to changes in *another* file (that is, if your preferences are in a file you named yourself), you should use `getSharedPreferences(String nameOfFile, int mode)`

[getSharedPreferences in android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int))